# Rails 4 + Materialize: Unable to find select box (Capybara::ElementNotFound)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, selenium, capybara, materialize

I am trying to make some test run after attach a html to my form, that html was made with materialize. I put it into my rails application but now, I'm getting an `Unable to find select box "purchase_customer_gender" (Capybara::ElementNotFound)` error.

In my step definition i have

```
When(/^I select "(.*?)" in "(.*?)"$/) do |value, field|
    select(value, from: field)
end
```

and in the feature i have, but also tried using, `purchase[customer_gender]`, even with `'Gender'` wich is the label.

```
And I select "M" in "purchase_customer_gender"
```

I already tried, with the follow:

```
When(/^I select "(.*?)" in "(.*?)"$/) do |value, field|
  within(:css, 'div.input.select.purchase_customer_gender') do
     select(value, from: field)
  end
end
```

`select(value, from: field, visible: false)` which throws me an `(Selenium::WebDriver::Error::ElementNotVisibleError)`

`page.select(value, from: field)`

...and finally my html

```
<%= simple_form_for :purchase, url: process_payment_url  do |f|%>
...
    <div class="input-field col s6">
       <%= f.input :customer_gender, label: "Gender", collection: ['M', 'F'] , required: true, label_html: { class: "validate" }%>
    </div>
...
<% end %>
```

which renders this n my browser

```
<div class="input-field col s6">
    <div class="input select required purchase_customer_gender">
      <select class="select required" name="purchase[customer_gender]" id="purchase_customer_gender">
        <option value="M">M</option>
        <option value="F">F</option>
      </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm using capybara-webkit, cucumber-rails, selenium-webdriver for testing and simple_form for formularies.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing materialize has actually hidden your select box and replaced it on screen with something built from <ul> and <li>s to enable styling, etc.  You need to look at the actual elements making up your "select" in the real browser and base your Capybara actions off that. Based on the examples of materialize [here](http://materializecss.com/forms.html) it's most likely something like

```
find('div.select-wrapper input', text: 'prompt of the select').click #open the dropdown
find('div.select-wrapper li', text: 'M').click #select the option wanted
```

Comment: Yes sir! that did the trick, I wasn't seeing the whole picture. Materialize indeed renders a hidden`select`, then uses that info to re-writtes the DOM.